# How to find a date or subsequent dates in excel with VBA

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I am writing a macro to find all entries on a worksheet for the proceeding week and select the first row to match the earliest date. 
I can make the macro find the first date (a week back) but cannot work out how to find the subsequent dates if the first date returns no matches.

E.G.
Todays date: 28Mar16. Macro will look back 7 days (21Mar16). If there are no entries for the 21Mar16, find the first entry dated 22Mar16. If no dates on that date, 23Mar16, etc.

Is this possible?

Here is the code so far:

```
    Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim strFilename As String
Dim rngRange As Range
Dim strfind As String

Set strfind = Worksheets("Report").Range("J1")
Set rngRange = Worksheets("Report").Range("B:B")

If opt1.Value = True Then
Cells.Find(what:=strfind, after:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlPart, _
    searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, searchformat:=False).Activate
If opt2.Value = True Then
Cells.Find(what:=strfind, after:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlPart, _
    searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, searchformat:=False).Activate



End If
'Range("A1:H100").Select
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
"C:\Desktop\Obs Diary Report week starting " & strFilename & ".pdf", Quality:= _
        xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=True
End Sub
```

Thanks,

Christian

Comment: I am sure it is possible. How is your data structured in the spreadsheet and can you post the macro you have so far?

Comment: Alex P,   Data in the spreadsheet is displayed so that each entry is on its own row, organised by:
Name     Date    Time     Title     Observation     etc etc.

Macro code has been added above.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell what would work in your data, but all you need to do is loop through the `Find` incrementing the date to search for by one each time, until you get to either today's date or find something.

Here is an example you can adapt to your needs:

```
Option Explicit
Sub OneWeekAgo()
    Dim dtEarliest As Date
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Dim R As Range

Set WS = ActiveSheet
dtEarliest = Date - 7

With WS.Cells
    Do Until Not R Is Nothing
        Set R = .Find(dtEarliest)
            dtEarliest = dtEarliest + 1
            If dtEarliest > Date Then
                Debug.Print "No Dates in Last Week"
                Exit Sub
            End If
    Loop
End With

If Not R Is Nothing Then
    Debug.Print R.Address, R.Text
End If

End Sub
```